# Помогите решить задание в debug

Tags: отладка

1. Очистить регистры ax, bx, сх.
2. Записать число (-160)10 в регистр ax.
3. Переслать результат в регистры bx, сх.
4. Прибавить к содержимому регистра ах содержимое ах

Comment: а debug вообще реально запустить сейчас? Я где то лет 10 назад его запускал.

Comment: @sathal, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@deterok](/users/13802/deterok)](/users/13802/deterok), при чем заданий не интересных, и не актуальных:). Скажите преподам что пора уже с debug переходить на какой то компилятор актуальный.

могу первое написать

```
xor ax, ax
xor bx, bx
xor cx, cx
```

Или

```
sub ax, ax
sub bx, bx
sub cx, cx
```

Дальше подумайте.